# Linking out to other websites and SEO

Tags: seo, redirects, links, link-building

I have searched for this, but couldn't find anyone actually asking this same question. I'd be happy to be pointed to a previous answer though.

I have built a one page website that links to other websites to provide people with links to unsubscription pages.

So I'm simply linking to those websites directly, however I have now thought that maybe I should be linking to my own website using an SEO optimised URL, that would then redirect to that page.

i.e. `www.mywebsite.com/?site=ebay-uk` which would then redirect to Ebay.

I'm not sure this actually makes any difference in terms of link building, but my website being a one page only kind of thing, I figured it could do with some internal linking, but I was just wondering if that would actually make any difference at all.

Would anyone be able to answer that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't do you any good SEO-wise.

1. Search engines are smart enough to follow the redirect so they'll give the final landing page the credit for the link.
2. Even if point #1 we not true, it would be silly to give a redirect page so much link juice and/or any other SEO value. Do you really want that page to rank well? Is that what you want your visitors to land on? Even with that link juice it would have no content so it would have nothing to rank well for anyway.

Comment: Good point. I have seen websites doing that, so wondered what it was all about. Thanks

Comment: It's likely to be for the purpose of tracking clicks, rather than for SEO reasons